# MailForm does not include a field from form when sending email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, email, ruby-on-rails-4, mail-form

I'm trying to set up [MailForm](https://github.com/plataformatec/mail_form) to send emails in my Rails 4 app and I actually got it working except for one thing.

For some reason it does not include the `message` field in emails (the form has only `name`, `email` and `message` fields, plus a hidden `nickname` field).

Here's how my `Contact` model looks like:

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base
  attribute :name,     validate: true
  attribute :email,    validate: /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  attribute :message
  attribute :nickname, captcha: true

  append :remote_ip, :user_agent

  def headers
    {
      subject: 'Question',
      to: ENV['ACTION_MAILER_USERNAME'],
      from: %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end
end
```

If I add `validate: true` to `attribute :message`, the validation will work incorrectly, i.e. it will say the field is empty even if it is not, so if I turn on the validation for the `:message` attribute, I cannot even submit the form.

In MailForm docs example there's no validation for `:message` field, though when I submit the form, the message that is sent to me contains only `:name` and `:email` fields, no `:message`.

My `ContactsController.rb` looks like this:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    @contact.request = request
    if @contact.deliver
      flash.now[:notice] = I18n.t('contact.message_success')
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash.now[:error] = I18n.t('contact.message_error')
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :message)
  end
end
```

And here's my html form:

```
   <%= simple_form_for @contact do |f| %>
       <%= f.input :name, required: true, label: false %>
       <%= f.input :email, required: true, label: false %>
       <%= f.input :message, as: :text, required: true, label: false %>
       <div class="hidden">
           <%= f.input :nickname, hint: 'Leave this field blank!' %>
       </div>
       <%= f.button :submit, t('contact.action') %>
   <% end %>
```

So, basically, I followed the examples in MailForm docs, but still couldn't get it working correctly.

Could you help me to find out what I'm doing wrong?

### Update 1

It seems like the problem is with params. Here's how `params` hash looks like when submitting the form:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kOtHaOTBNvl5KpPBLB31LtQ6W0jUoohg012ZbQ5qyg0fAGW6y5mMR5FSAEcY4kyotFYihTvRSvTtbDsc8oMQ3g==", "contact"=>{"name"=>"Testing", "email"=>"whatever@test.com", "nickname"=>""}, "Message"=>"Hello everyone!", "commit"=>"Send", "locale"=>"en"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's how I got it working:

Because the `params` hash looked like this:

`{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kOtHaOTBNvl5KpPBLB31LtQ6W0jUoohg012ZbQ5qyg0fAGW6y5mMR5FSAEcY4kyotFYihTvRSvTtbDsc8oMQ3g==", "contact"=>{"name"=>"Testing", "email"=>"whatever@test.com", "nickname"=>""}, "Message"=>"Hello everyone!", "commit"=>"Send", "locale"=>"en"}`

I could not get the message field because when I did `params.require(:contact)` it only returned me the hash like this: `{"name"=>"Testing", "email"=>"whatever@test.com", "nickname"=>""}`, and the message field wasn't inside the `:contact`.

So I had to change my `contact_params` method to look like this:

```
  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email)
                            .merge(message: params.fetch('Message'))
  end
```

and now it returns what I need, i.e. a hash like this:

```
{"name"=>"Testing", "email"=>"whatever@test.com", "message"=>"Hello everyone!"}
```

---

Hope it helps somebody!